# CakePHP: Append default string to Page Titles

Tags: cakephp, controller, append, title

I'm setting individual page titles in my controllers' actions using:

```
$this->set( 'title_for_layout', 'Some Title' );
```

What I want to achieve is append a site title string to all these titles before rendering, i.e. say, **"Some Title :: Site Name"**.

The easiest way out would be to add this string manually to each point where the page title is set - but that's like the brute force way.

What I tried was to override the `beforeRender()` method of each controller and add this statement:

```
$this->set( 'title_for_layout', $this->title_for_layout . ' &raquo; ' . Configure::read( 'Site.title' ) );
```

I thought this would append the site's title to the page title for each action - but what I get instead is:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: SomeController::title_for_layout [APP\controllers\some_controller.php, line xx]
```

It seems like the `title_for_layout` (set in individual actions in the controller) hasn't been set yet - which is throwing up this error.

My question is, where & How can I append the site title globally to all page titles - if not in this way?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$this->pageTitle` instead of `$this->title_for_layout`

Comment: That's what I had tried at first but $this->pageTitle doesn't seem to work and I read in another post on Nabble that $this->pageTitle has been deprecated in Cake 1.3.x in favour of title_for_layout. Moreover, it produces the same Undefined var notice.

Comment: aw, sorry, coming from cakephp1.2 =/

Comment: for one, I don't think you can access $this->title_for_layout in the controller, as it never been set in the controller, but rather in the view (thus the $this->set('title_for_layout') ).

Comment: Another tip is, if you want to make it applicablein all controllers, instead of doing it in every controller, you can do it in app_controller.php beforeRender() method

Comment: Yup thanks. I'm playing around with app_controller.php now... But still got to figure out how to avoid having to set it in every single view and be able to do it from a single point :)

Comment: put the appending inside app/views/layout/default.ctp

Comment: Aahh.. I managed to get it done through the view :) Still there must be some more elegant way of doing the same out there. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to append the *same* string to *all* your page titles, put it in the layout after $title_for_layout.